# Iteravely generate keys and count number of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a way to iterate your way through a dictionary to count the number of words with the string stored within the dictionary, and save it as a new dictionary that returns the word count for each item of that key?

For example...

```
#Input:
inputdict = {
    'key1': 'The brown fox is brown and a fox.', 
    'key2': 'The red dog is the red and is a dog.'
}

newdict = {}
for k, v in inputdict:
    newdict(str(k) + "_" + str(v)) = count(v)

#Output:     
newdict = {
    'key1_the': 1, 'key1_brown': 2, 'key1_is': 1, # ...
    'key2_the': 2, 'key2_red': 2, # ...
}
```

Side Note:
This is kind of a follow up from an article at https://janav.wordpress.com/2013/10/27/tf-idf-and-cosine-similarity/.  Where instead of reading in strings I'm trying to read in items from a dictionary.

Comment: `for k, v in inputdict:` should be `for k, v in inputdict.items():`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just use the [`collections.Counter()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with a generator expression producing the values you want to count:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(f"{k}_{word}" for k, v in inputdict.items() for word in v.split())
```

I've assumed a simple split on whitespace is sufficient, but if you need something more sophisticated then replace `v.split()` with something that produces an iterable of words to count.

`Counter()` is a subclass of `dict`, but with a few extra methods to help handle counts.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> inputdict = {
...     'key1': 'The brown fox is brown and a fox.',
...     'key2': 'The red dog is the red and is a dog.'
... }

>>> Counter(f"{k}_{word}" for k, v in inputdict.items() for word in v.split())
Counter({'key1_brown': 2, 'key2_red': 2, 'key2_is': 2, 'key1_The': 1, 'key1_fox': 1, 'key1_is': 1, 'key1_and': 1, 'key1_a': 1, 'key1_fox.': 1, 'key2_The': 1, 'key2_dog': 1, 'key2_the': 1, 'key2_and': 1, 'key2_a': 1, 'key2_dog.': 1})
```

Personally, I'd produce separate counts, using a nested dictionary structure:

```
{key: Counter(value.split()) for key, value in inputdict.items()}
```

and so produce:

```
{'key1': Counter({'brown': 2, 'The': 1, 'fox': 1, ... }),
 'key2': Counter({'red': 2, 'is': 2, 'The': 1, ... })}
```

so you can access counts *per sentence*, with `newdict["key1"]` and `newdict["key2"]`.